# Infinite scroll with plain text

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I would like to implement an infinite scroll feature but there are some things which make it very hard to do that:

1. I would like a more or less fixed window height.
2. So normally I would compare a window scrollTop with the difference between a document height and a window height, append to the bottom and remove from the top, adjust the scrollTop. Easy.
3. BUT. I can't append. In my `body` tag I have either a mixture of HTML and plain text or just a plain text.
4. So I figured I'd use something like this

```
    l=18000;
    //start length
    sw=3000;
    //scrolling window
    j=0;
    const html=$("body").html();
    if (scrollToBottom) {
      $("body").html(html.slice(j,l+sw));
      var ph=$("body").height();
      var result=html.slice(j+l,sw+l);
      $("body").html(result);
      var ch=$("body").height();
      var st=$(window).scrollTop-ph+ch;
      $(window).scrollTop(st);
    } else if (scrollToTop) {
      //the same
    }
```

It works but works very poorly. Sometimes scroll position is slightly wrong. Moreover, in some cases I end up with scroll jumping to the top and triggering scroll bottom or vice versa.

I wonder if there is a better approach or some existing plugin for this task. I really need infinite scroll as I do language processing and some other a little bit heavy stuff on the text.

Answer (score 0):

See, if you can achieve this using a popular jQuery plugin: https://infinite-scroll.com/.

Comment: This plugin was the first thing I checked. It wouldn't work.